# R query: adding a header row to .txt files

Tags: dataset, addition, header-row

I have 7 datasets (53 variables each with varying numbers of rows, all > 100k) in *.txt* format. There is no header row but I know the field names and correct formats for each variable.  I have tried using rbind:

```
df <- read.csv("filepath_to_textfile.txt", header = FALSE, 
                as.is = TRUE,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

new_df <- rbind(c(hadm_id, subject_id,... obsinl24), df)
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in rbind(c(hadm_id, subject_id, ....  :    object 'hadm_id' not
>   found

I have also tried creating a dataframe:

```
fieldnames <- data.frame(hadm_id=integer(),
                           subject_id=integer(), ...
                           obsinl24)
```

but get the following error:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :    cannot
>   coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Answer (score 0):

The following code did just what I needed:

df <- read.csv("filepath_to_textfile.txt", header = FALSE, 
                as.is = TRUE,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(df) <- c("hadm_id", "subject_id",... "obsinl24")